# 'No value given for one or more required parameters' IN Operator

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 2007 VBA

Tables in Excel Sheet

using ADODB Connection and Recordset

This works:

```
select * 
from [tblBFLC$] 
where [Body ID] IN (select  DISTINCT [Body ID]  
     from [tblBody$] 
     where [Luminaire Type]  = 'Interior') and  [LED Type]  = 'COB'
```

This **does not** work:

```
select * 
from [tblBFLC$] 
where [Family ID] IN (select  DISTINCT [Family ID]  
     from [tblFamily$] 
     where [Family]  = 'ACLAP') and  [LED Type]  = 'COB'
```

I have checked for correct Field names.

Syntax Error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters

Comment: No value given for one or more required parameters

i get this error

Comment: Can you provide a minimal set of sample data which makes this problem reproducible ?

Comment: Does `select  DISTINCT [Family ID]  from [tblFamily$] where [Family]  = 'ACLAP'` by itself work?  What about the second query minus the `IN` ?

Comment: I checked and it does not work minus IN...

Comment: There was small mistake in one of the Field names, SQL worked on other Fields.. Problem solved.